# Can I create and publish extension to the Chrome Store from my website?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to build a website where I will be able to create an extension and then publish it automatically to the Chrome Store. So my question is can I published it automatically?

Comment: There is an [API](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api) you can implement.

Comment: But won't I need to create new item manually in the Developer Dashboard?

Comment: The documentation I linked to covers uploading new items and updating existing items.